# request.FILES empty when submiting form through javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-file-upload

I am trying to sumbit a form in django that has a file on it. The form is the following and is placed in the body of a modal dialog

```
<form action="{%url 'customer-upload-xray' customer_id=customer_id%}" method="post" id="xrayform">
    {%csrf_token%}        
    <div class="form-group date">
        <label for="id_date">Date</label>
        <input class="form-control input-sm datepicker input-append date" id="id_date" name="date" readonly="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_type">Type</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" id="id_type" name="type">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
            <option value="Observation">Observation</option>
            <option value="Initial">Initial</option>
            <option value="Progress">Progress</option>
            <option value="Final">Final</option>
            <option value="Post Treatment">Post Treatment</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_desc">Desc</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" id="id_desc" name="desc">
            <option value="PA Ceph">PA Ceph</option>
            <option value="Lateral Ceph">Lateral Ceph</option>
            <option value="Panoramic">Panoramic</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_image1">Image1</label>
        <input id="id_image1" name="image1" type="file">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_image2">Image2</label>
        <input id="id_image2" name="image2" type="file">
    </div>
                    \
</form>
```

I have a button with id = upload and my js code looks as the following

```
$("#upload").on('click', function(){
    form = $("#xrayform");
    form.submit();

});
```

But the request.FILES is an empty dict. How is it not passing the files on the dictionary when posting?

EDIT: How about putting some enctype on the form you would say right?? Damn me!!! Please the moderators delete the question if they don't want to keep it

Comment: i was going to say that :) enctype="multipart/form-data"